# Global list modified inside function is empty

Tags: python, scikit-learn, global-variables

I have two lists that I create outside my function. Inside this function, which is called multiple times, these two lists are extended. The problem is that after I finished my computations, the two lists are empty. Here's the code I'm using:

```
true_classes = []
predicted_classes = []

def report_cv(y_true, y_pred):
    true_classes.extend(y_true)
    predicted_classes.extend(y_pred)

    return accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)

cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True)
rfr = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000, class_weight='balanced', 
                         n_jobs=-1)

scores = cross_val_score(rfr, 
                    X=data_ml_clean.iloc[:, 2:], 
                    y=data_ml_clean.vDili, 
                    cv=cv, n_jobs=-1, 
                    scoring=make_scorer(report_cv))

print(classification_report(true_classes, predicted_classes))
```

I do not understand why they are not treated like global variables. Adding `global true_classes` inside the function does not help.

Comment: where is classification_report() defined?

Comment: It's a Scikit-learn function.

Comment: `report_cv` is not being called or it is being called with empty iterators as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I had another look at this, have worked out what is probably wrong, but first your code with some additions:

```
true_classes = []
predicted_classes = []

def report_cv(y_true, y_pred):
    global true_classes
    global predicted_classes
    true_classes.extend(y_true)
    predicted_classes.extend(y_pred)

    return accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)

cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True)
rfr = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000, class_weight='balanced', 
                         n_jobs=-1)

def calculate_scores():
    # (no global keyword needed here)
    scores = cross_val_score(rfr,
    X=data_ml_clean.iloc[:, 2:],
    y=data_ml_clean.vDili,
    cv=cv, n_jobs=-1,
    scoring=make_scorer(report_cv))  # this call to report_cv should set the two global variables
    print(true_classes)
    print(predicted_classes)

a = report_cv(actual_y_true, actual_y_pred)

print(classification_report(true_classes, predicted_classes))
```

So you only need the `global` keyword in the function which will set their values when it is first called as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/423596/4288043).

Then, and this is really what the problem is, as @Goyo mentioned, `report_cv` is not being called. From the scikit learn docs:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html

> This factory function wraps scoring functions for use in GridSearchCV
>   and cross_val_score. It takes a score function, such as
>   accuracy_score, mean_squared_error, adjusted_rand_index or
>   average_precision and returns a callable that scores an estimator’s
>   output.

So *returns a callable*, *wraps*, do not imply *calls*.

I put in a line to call `report_cv`. You will need to give it values. This will make the global variables behave as you are expecting, list should no longer be empty, but I can't promise it will make the rest of this sklearn code behave as expected.

Comment: Thanks but it does not work. The two lists are still empty!

Comment: @wrong_path have you fixed it yet? For the purposes of debugging this, can you add additional `print(1, true_classes)` and `print(1, predicted_classes)` to your first function report_cv before the return statement and see if the lists even there are empty or not.

Comment: Not yet. I don't know what's wrong. If I print the list inside the function, they are not empty but they are overwritten each time.

Comment: And are they empty the very last time they are written?

Comment: No, they contain the predicted and true values of that *iteration*.

Answer (score 0):

report_cv function is not called actually, try to build a lambda function or what you can except that is you can call report_cv function first and then save its value and use it further